# Formula Text value not appearing in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I'd like to show the value of the formula text field.  The formula text field is `{!v.opptyOwnerName.Account_Name__c}` but on the lightning page the value doesn't appear.  FYI the Accounts `{!v.opptyOwnerName.Accounts_KYC_Approved__c}` field also is a Formula Text field.(see image below)   Any thoughts?

Formula: IF(LEN(Account.Name)>50, LEFT(Account.Name,50),Account.Name)
 [image]

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="showOpportunity" type="Object"/> <!-- used for target record -->
<aura:attribute name="opptyOwnerName" type="Object"/><!-- used for targetFields-->
<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String" 
                description="An error message bound to force:recordData"/>
<force:recordData aura:id="OpptyRecord"
                  recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
                  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
                  targetRecord="{!v.showOpportunity}"
                  targetFields="{!v.opptyOwnerName}"
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  mode="EDIT"
                  recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdated}"/>
     <!-- recordId displays the record you currently are on,
targetfields must be specified to display later or use layout=FULL -->

<lightning:card iconName="standard:opportunity" title="{!v.opptyOwnerName.Name}" >

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.opptyOwnerName.StageName == '1 - Prospect'}">
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">

        <p class="slds-text-heading--small">
            <b>Account:</b> <lightning:formattedText  value="{!v.opptyOwnerName.Account_Name__c}" /></p>
        <p class="slds-text-heading--small">
            <b>Accounts KYC Approved:</b> <lightning:formattedText value="{!v.opptyOwnerName.Accounts_KYC_Approved__c}" /></p>
        <p class="slds-text-heading--small">
            <b>Pricebook:</b> <lightning:formattedText value="{!v.opptyOwnerName.Pricebook2Id}" /></p>
        </div>
    </aura:if>

<!-- Display Lightning Data Service errors, if any -->
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordError))}">
<div class="recordError">
    {!v.recordError}
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. It would be super helpful if you could also include the actual formula for this field - I would suspect that the value is evaluating to something blank but can't be sure since you didn't provide this detail.

Comment: Sorry about that, here is the formula: Data Type FormulaThis formula references multiple objects    
IF(LEN(Account.Name)>50, LEFT(Account.Name,50),Account.Name)     Please keep in mind the value appears on the page layout.

Comment: Make sure that the field and its value is in opptyOwnerName. You said that the field is in the layout and that is important too when using force:recordData

Comment: Thanks that was the problem! I didn't know it had to be in the layout!  Is it possible to pull data from the Opportunity owner such as display their image, phone , email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the field to the layout for the field value to display in the lightning card.

Comment: The canned response doesn't do so well in this situation. I do think going into a bit more detail would help this answer.

Comment: @DerekF  The field had to be added to the page layout...that's what worked for me.  I would have posted the code if I made a change to the code.  Do you want me to show how to add fields to page layouts?